# jQuery mobile: how to add a checkbox in header of collapsible item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I want to add a checkbox in the header of a collapsible item.
When I click the checkbox, the collapsible item should not open.
When I click at the label, it should open.

See what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/heidewitzka/UwkWx/34/

```
$('.ui-icon-checkbox-on').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('label').attr( "data-icon", "checkbox-off" );
  $(this).addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
  $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on');
  $(this).closest('label').addClass('ui-checkbox-off');
  $(this).closest('label').removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');
});

$('.ui-icon-checkbox-off').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('label').attr( "data-icon", "checkbox-on" );
  $(this).addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on');
  $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
  $(this).closest('label').addClass('ui-checkbox-on');
  $(this).closest('label').removeClass('ui-checkbox-off');
});
```

All works fine, but I cannot deselct the checkbox. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is you updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/UwkWx/124/)**

I added an ID to the label containing the checkbox and then put a single click handler on the .ui-icon found within the label.  In here, you check which icon class is currently assigned and then toggle it:

```
$('#checkBoxLbl .ui-icon').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on')) {
        $(this).closest('label').attr("data-icon", "checkbox-off");
        $(this).addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on');
        $(this).closest('label').addClass('ui-checkbox-off');
        $(this).closest('label').removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('label').attr("data-icon", "checkbox-on");
        $(this).addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
        $(this).closest('label').addClass('ui-checkbox-on');
        $(this).closest('label').removeClass('ui-checkbox-off');
    }
});
```

The problem with what you had is that both handlers were actually pointing to the same DOM element (icon SPAN).